# Win10 Cannot Access C Drive As Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions, administrator

I just upgraded to Win10 and as an Administrator my account does not have write privlages to access the root of the C: drive.  From the Properties | Security | Advanced settings of the disk I have changed ownership from TrustedInstaller to my_machine\Administrators and rebooted.  The local Administrators group has full control of the drive and my account is an Administrator account.  Yet, I still can't write to C: root from my account.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS did you upgrade from?  Are all your Apps updated?  Sometimes it is necessary to do a Windows 10 Repair Install after upgrading.  Try (from an Admin Command Prompt)  dism.exe   /online  /cleanup-image   /restorehealth  and then restart oand test

Comment: You should not be storing files in `C:\ `. Messing with ownership and permissions can result in serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I generally agree with the above for many users.  Without any permission changes of any kind, I have C:\General_Storage on two Windows 10 computers for easy syncing between both.

Comment: Upgraded from Win7 which didn't give me problems and all apps/drivers are up to date.  I've run sfc/scan now and dism with a reboot without incident.  I'm a long time user and your point is well taken regarding the reasoning to not store files there but I have a need sometimes and for personal convenience.  This machine is on a private local network and I understand the risk. The only access I have is to add/remove folders even though I am an Administrator.

Comment: Given your issue, I strongly suggest trying a Repair Install, Keep Everything to correct numerous issues.  Also try a different User Account (Profile)

Comment: @John thanks for the help but a repair install isn't in the cards because its way too risky.   So I tried to add another admin account for testing and sure enough another problem shows up.  I can add a user but they don't show up in "Family & other people" like they should. I can get to them through lusrmgr.msc.  I had zero problems with this admin stuff under Win7.  So far Win10 is a big bust IMHO.

Comment: I have no issues that you have posted on my (several) Windows 10 machines.  Also, Windows Repair has not been risky for me (done quite a few) but I also have good backups also.

Comment: Sucks to be me.  So adding a new admin user has the same restrictions.  Also, Windows Backup / System Image fails too (I have another thread about that). I just installed Reflect and was able to take an image of the drive so at least I'm protected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10, Microsoft does not want us saving files to the root folder of C.

This is not recommended, but it is still possible to write to `C:\` when
the writing program is run as administrator.

Comment: I just tried that to see how screwed up things are and it turns out I don't think they are foobar at all.  I ran an elevated cmd window as Administrator and can create files to c root!  So it must be that my shell isn't running as an admin.  That could also explain why I keep getting told that I need to provide admin privs to remove some files and clicking OK removes them.  Can this possibly be the "normal" operation of Win10?

Comment: Windows 10 runs programs with reduced permissions even when the login is admin. Explicit elevation is required for running with full permissions. What was the Administrator account in previous versions is now disabled by default (do not re-enable!).

Comment: That nailed it.  This came up when I tried to zip up a folder on the root using 7Zip.  I used to be able to just right click the folder and send it to an archive which defaults the destination to the current folder (c root).  Now it fails and I have to go through the app and run it as admin.  That works.

Comment: It would perhaps be simpler to create a work folder, rather than using the root.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I solved this problem via the registry and can now write to the root of the C drive.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\

Change EnableLUA from 1 to 0 and restart.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpsb/958053ae-5397-4f96-977f-b7700ee461ec

I also previously set UAC to 'Never notify', but I don't know if that is relevant.

My computer is my own and I prefer being open with information.